# Jboss 7 storage log files

Tags: logging, jboss7.x

dear reader!

I have some specific question about logging on jboss. Firstly, my english is bad, i'm sorry for it))

How can i storage my log files in jboss 7 more than 6 month, and all log files in the archived, other than this(last) month?

For example,

```
log.2018.09.11.gz
log.2018.09.30.gz
log.2018.10.01
```

Waiting for an answer, dear reader!
Thank you!

Comment: I guess a rollingfileappender is already provided by log4j , you might want to check log4j.xml

Comment: You'd probably have to use something like a cronjob to do this. There is no way out of the box. JBoss AS 7 also doesn't use log4j as the log manager.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins, thank you for the answer, i just use logrotate